# How can i connect a Wireless Computer to my Local Area Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

How can I connect a Wireless Computer to my Local Area Network?

I have no idea how to do this but here is my current setup:

> 14 Computers on the same network 192.168.1.xx
> 1 Wireless Computer connected via wireless network adapter (currently connected to ISP MODEM1)
> 1 Linksys LRT224 DUAL WAN router (192.168.1.5)
> 1 ISP MODEM1 (192.168.254.253) (Static IP, DHCP Enabled)
> 1 ISP MODEM2 (192.168.254.253) (Static IP, DHCP Enabled)
> 1 24 port switch TP LINK
>
> MODEM1 CONNECTED TO  Linksys as PRIMARY WAN (WAN1)
> MODEM2 CONNECTED TO  Linksys as SECONDARY WAN (WAN2, UPBACK INTERNET)
> Linksys CONNECTED To 24 PORT SWITCH TP LINK
> TP LINK SWITCH CONNECTED TO 14 COMPUTERS EXCEPT 1 (WIRELESS, 192.168.254.xx)

My question here is, how can make the wireless computer in the same network as all the 14 computers, I want to make its IP like `192.168.1.xx` so that I can add it on the same homegroup I created.

I can make it `192.168.1.xx` but still I can't see it on the network and it has no internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy ann AP (AccessPoint) and put into the switch and you configure the DHCP of the AP with the network 192.168.1.X

Other option is to replace 1 Linksys LRT224 DUAL WAN router with other similar model with wirelles